# Maximizing nonlinear-constraints-problem using R-package "nloptr"

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

I need to maximize the objective function for some problems using R package 'nloptr'. I tried the basic rule "Maximize f(x) <=> Minimize -f(x)" but it does not work. I am not sure what's wrong either using it or there is some other way.

Here is a complete example. The current solution is just the initial vector with minimum objective value. But, I am supposed to get the solution that would maximize the objective function. Can someone please help me how to get it. Thanks!

```
library(nloptr)
X = log(rbind(c(1.350, 8.100),   
          c(465.000,     423.000),
          c(36.330  ,    119.500),
          c(27.660   ,   115.000), 
          c(1.040     ,  5.500),
          c(11700.000, 50.000),  
          c(2547.000  ,  4603.000),
          c(187.100    , 419.000), 
          c(521.000  ,   655.000), 
          c(10.000    ,  115.000), 
          c(3.300    ,   25.600),  
          c(529.000   ,  680.000), 
          c(207.000  ,   406.000), 
          c(62.000    ,  1320.000),
          c(6654.000 ,   5712.000),
          c(9400.000  ,  70.000),  
          c(6.800      , 179.000), 
          c(35.000   ,   56.000),  
          c(0.120  ,     1.000),   
          c(0.023   ,    0.400),   
          c(2.500  ,     12.100),  
          c(55.500  ,    175.000), 
          c(100.000  ,   157.000), 
          c(52.160   ,   440.000), 
          c(87000.000 ,  154.500), 
          c(0.280  ,     1.900),   
          c(0.122  ,     3.000),   
          c(192.000 ,    180.000)))
n = nrow(X)
q = 0.5
x0 = cbind(8,4)
x01 = x0[1]
x02 = x0[2]
x1 = X[,1]
x2 = X[,2]
pInit = c(0.1614860, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 
          0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 
          0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.7124934, 0.0000000, 0.0000000,
          0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 
          0.1260206, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000)

eval_f0 = function(p) {
  obj0 = mean((n * p ) ^ q)
  grad0 = rbind(q * ((n * p) ^ (q - 1))/((mean((n * p ) ^ q))^2))
  return(list("objective" = obj0, "gradient" = grad0))
}

eval_g_eq0 = function(p) {
  sum0 = sum(x1 * p) - x01
  sum1 =  sum(x2 * p) - x02
  sum2 = sum(p) - 1
  constr0 = rbind(sum0, sum1, sum2)
  grad0 = rbind(x1, x2, rep(1,n))
  return(list("constraints" = constr0, "jacobian" = grad0))
}

local_opts <- list( "algorithm" = "NLOPT_LD_AUGLAG",
                    "xtol_rel" = 1.0e-7 )
opts <- list( "algorithm" = "NLOPT_LD_AUGLAG",
              "xtol_rel" = 1.0e-7,
              "maxeval" = 10000,
              "local_opts" = local_opts )

  res1 = nloptr(x0 = c(pInit), 
                eval_f = eval_f0, 
                lb = c(rep(0, n)), 
                ub = c(rep(Inf, n)), 
                eval_g_eq = eval_g_eq0, 
                opts = opts )

  weight = res1$solution
  fval0 = res1$objective

print(list(fval0, weight))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the Gradient (and Jacobian) at your starting point `pInit` is not finite which makes this task difficult for any gradient-based solver. I will use a different starting point, a bit away from the boundary.

Anyway, it seems easier to find the maximum with the Lagrangian solver in the *alabama* package. With your definitions above up to `x1 = X[,1]; x2 = X[,2]` a possible solution looks like:

```
f1 <- function(p) mean((n * p ) ^ q)
heq1 <- function(p) 
    c(sum(x1 * p) - x01, sum(x2 * p) - x02, sum(p) - 1)
```

For simplicity we let the solver calculate gradients and Jacobians. To find the maximum apply the solver to the negative of the objective function.

```
sol <- alabama::auglag(rep(0.1, 28), fn=function(p) -f1(p), heq=heq1)
cat("The maximum value is:", -sol$value, '\n')
## The maximum value is: 0.7085338
```

The equality conditions are satisfied, see

```
heq1(sol$par)
## [1] -1.685957e-08  3.721533e-08 -2.935964e-08
```

and the solution found is

```
sol$par
##  [1] 0.012186842 0.006640286 0.006706268 0.006418224 0.014501609 0.405618998  
##  [7] 0.003531462 0.005458189 0.005582029 0.005158098 0.008072278 0.005510394  
## [13] 0.005653117 0.002935642 0.003861549 0.123009564 0.004021866 0.009866779  
## [19] 0.024385229 0.027101557 0.011436010 0.006184886 0.007473135 0.004162962  
## [25] 0.245429952 0.019978294 0.010919515 0.008195238
```

I would be interested to know whether this is a reasonable solution for you! I checked it for several starting points and it always came out the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer in detail. Pointing out the problem is highly appreciable. However, setting the starting point manually is not applicable in my case. I provided a simple example where initial point was generated on the basis of theoretical idea behind this. Actually, I have to use it in simulation study where it would be calculated by the program in every replication.

Comment: You have to avoid zero components in your starting vector in any case when applying a gradient-based optimization solver -- there is no way around it. The good news is: Adding a small, nonzero amount to `pInit`, such as `pInit+0.001`, will result in the same maximum. and this can be done programmatically. (Or you add `0.001` to only those components that are zero.)

Comment: There is another problem: When we use this procedure to run simulations, it gives an error "Error in eigen(a$hessian, symmetric = TRUE, only.values = TRUE) : 
  infinite or missing values in 'x'". I don't know how to point out and overcome this.

Comment: You could have given us a hint that you have opened a new question [Error in nonlinear optimization problem: infinite or missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130611/error-in-nonlinear-optimization-problem-infinite-or-missing-values-in-x/) for addressing the error message.